# Fetching icon image of apps from itunes using SimpleHTMLDOM parser

Tags: php, html-parsing, itunes, simple-html-dom

I am trying to fetch icon and screenshot images from itunes app url.However I can only fetch screenshot of a particular app. Incase of a icon, I get the following url https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/ef35/frameworks/images/p.png for all apps.I can fetch both icon and screenshot in case of google play.**So does itunes restrict the fetching of icon images or is there a error in my code?**

```
 <?php
 // Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

//base url
     $base = "https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/kindle/id405399194?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D2";

   if (strpos($base, 'play.google.com') !== false) {

     $html_base = file_get_html( $base );
     $icon = "https:".$html_base->find('div[class=details-info] img[class=cover-image]')[0]->src;
     echo  $icon."<br>";
     $screenShot = "https:".$html_base->find('div[class=screenshot-align-inner] img')[0]->src;
     echo $screenShot;

}elseif (strpos($base,'itunes.apple.com') !== false) {

     $html_base = file_get_html( $base );
     $icon = $html_base->find('div[class=artwork] img')[4]->src;
     echo  $icon."<br>";
     $screenShot = $html_base->find('div[class=lockup] img')[0]->src;
     echo $screenShot;

}
 $html_base->clear();
 unset($html_base);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using src-swap instead of src as src does not fetch the actual image path.

```
}elseif (strpos($base,'itunes.apple.com') !== false) {

 $html_base = file_get_html( $base );
 $icon = $html_base->find('div[class=artwork] img')[4]->{'src-swap'};
 //the main icon for itunes is atleast 175px
 echo  $icon."<br>";
 $screenShot = $html_base->find('div[class=lockup] img')[0]->src;
 echo $screenShot;
}
```